# Angular 5 cannot display interface object to html

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular5

My server gives me json that looks like this.

```
[
{
    "userId": 11,
    "positionId": 2,
    "emailAddress": "ada.lovelace@gmail.com",
    "username": "adalovelace",
    "createdBy": 1,
    "createdAt": "2018-01-06 13:43:18",
    "updatedBy": null,
    "updatedAt": "2018-01-06 13:43:18",
    "profile": {
        "userProfileId": 1,
        "userId": 11,
        "displayName": "adalovelace",
        "location": null,
        "title": null,
        "imageUrl": null,
        "about": null,
        "threadCount": 0,
        "threadPostCount": 1,
        "threadKarma": 0,
        "threadPostKarma": 2
    }
}
]
```

my .ts files looks like this, I have removed a lot of unrelated codes.

```
import { UserService } from '../_shared/services/user.service';
import { UserInterface } from '../_shared/interfaces/user.interface';

export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

private currentUser = <UserInterface>{};

public username: string;

public userProfile = <UserInterface>{};

ngOnInit() {
    this.userSubcription = this.userService.showProfile(this.username)
        .subscribe((userProfile: UserInterface) => {
            this.userProfile = userProfile;
            console.log(this.userProfile); // has value!
        }, error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

}
```

.html file

```
<section id="profile">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h2>{{userProfile.userId}}</h2>
            <h2>{{userProfile.profile.dsplayName}}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It does not show me anything. userProfile.profile.dsplayName even gives me error. It says undefined.

User interface looks like this.

```
import { UserProfileInterface } from './user-profile.interface';

export interface UserInterface {
userId: number;
token: string;
username: string;
emailAddress: string;
createdBy: string;
createdAt: string;
updatedBy: string;
updatedAt: string;

positionId: number;
password: string;
confirmPassword: string;

profile: UserProfileInterface;
}
```

Is it because I'm using interface? I have another similar page that uses interface with interface array inside but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server returns json array. Try following code snippet

```
<section id="profile">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h2>{{userProfile[0].userId}}</h2>
            <h2>{{userProfile[0].profile.dsplayName}}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```